# Firefox: How to Create Shortcut or Button to "Manage Data" (cookies/storage manager)

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, cookies

I would like to have a button to take me here: Tools -> Options -> Privacy & Security -> (scroll down) -> Manage Data.  (Load the cookie manager.)

I do this continuously, and all the buttons and scrolling is a pain.

I searched for an addon that adds a button to load Firefox's cookie manager, but I can't find one.  I know one existed for a much older version of Firefox.

I also searched for Firefox shortcuts.  There are no matches for "cookies" on Firefox's page for that.

How do I got about adding my own button to the top/right tool button location?

(Also, I'm amazed at what garage all the top-ranked cookie manager addon's are.  I wasted an hour trying a bunch of them.  The standard Firefox cookie manager is fine, I just want to be able to get directly there.)

Comment: I'm not interested in "Clear Recent History" Ctrl-Shift-Del.

Comment: Searching for an answer I see that a lot of people want this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a direct link to a full-window version of Manage Data:

```
chrome://browser/content/preferences/dialogs/siteDataSettings.xhtml
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.

Comment: For other interested persons, you can add this link to the Bookmarks Toolbar, and then set the toolbar so it only opens on new tabs, in case you are like me and don't like the lost real estate from having the bookmarks toolbar always being there. Firefox won't let you add this type of link to the start page / top sites.